# How to reference a custom metadata in Aura component?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I have an Aura component that calls an external CSS thru `<ltng:require>` tags. I need to save the URLs in a custom metadata or maybe custom label in Salesforce rather than hardcoded URLs in the **.cmp**

Snippet of **.CMP**

````
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                           'https://simpleui-test-au.vixverify.com/df/javascripts/greenidConfig.js', 
                           'https://simpleui-test-au.vixverify.com/df/javascripts/greenidui.min.js')}" 
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{! c.onLoadScript }"/>

   <ltng:require styles="https://simpleui-test-au.vixverify.com/df/assets/stylesheets/greenid-mobile.css"/> ```
````

Comment: External CSS isn’t recommended by Salesforce and is considered a security issue. It’s better to upload the CSS as a static resource to your org and reference them resource in your Aura conponent. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_resource_value_provider.htm

Comment: Thanks, but uploading the CSS as a static resource is not the recommended way of GreenID - the biometrics software product we're implementing. It has to be via URL only.

Answer (score 0):

H newbiedev,

You can access the value of a Custom Label in your Aura Component markup by using the following syntax inside an expression: (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm)

```
$Label.c.labelName
```

So you could use it in your require tag as follows once the Custom Labels are created:

````
<ltng:require scripts="{!join(',',
                       $Label.c.MyLabel1, 
                       $Label.c.MyLabel2)}" 
              afterScriptsLoaded="{! c.onLoadScript }"/>

<ltng:require styles="{!$Label.c.MyLabel3}"/> ```
````

Comment: Hi Óscar, Thanks - will try this. Can I ask if you do mentoring?